# how to destroy a screen after navigating from it in StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react navigation. I have a StackNavigator

```html
const Stack = StackNavigator( // eslint-disable-line new-cap
    {
      List: {
        screen: DrugPage,
      },
      Create: {
        screen: DrugCreate,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'List',
    }
  );
```

The first screen is a list of entities and the second screen is to create a new entity that will add to the list. The first List screen has a nice link to 'Add Entity' in the navigation bar which goes to the Create route. After creating the entity I use navigation.navigate to go back to the List route. This leaves the create entity screen on the stack and so then a back button appears in the nav bar on my list screen. I don't want the Create Entity screen to remain in the stack after the entity is successfully created--I want it destroyed so Create screens don't build up in a stack that I don't need and so I don't have a back button I don't want on the List screen. I thought about using a StackNavigator but that doesn't give you a nice navbar at the top (in iOS). Any recommendations?

Comment: You can use the [following](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions) action types while navigating. The ones you need would be `reset`, `popToTop`

Answer (score 11):

I had a problem very similar to yours, and after days searching I was able to solve my problem by adding a line of code, which in my case destroys the screen as soon as it leaves it.

add this to the properties of drawerNavigator : `unmountInactiveRoutes: true`

follows an example of my code :

```
const drawMenu = createDrawerNavigator({
   StackHome,
   StackOS
},{
   unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
   initialRouteName: 'StackHome'
  }
);
```

Comment: This fixed my problem as well.  I searched a descent amount of time, not sure why I missed this answer, but I think it should be the accepted one?

Comment: Glad you could have helped! the questioner should not have seen my answer

Comment: You here unmount all routes . 
For unmount specific route I provide answer down 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74631456/14157959

Answer (score 6):

I used the reset action in NavigationActions per @Pritish Vaidya's comment on my original question. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset)

## Implementation

```js
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'List'})],
          key: null,
        });

navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: Am interested to know how you used this in context?

Comment: I can't find `NavigationsActions`

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest way is to use pop(), then you navigate to main screen**

```
navigation.pop();
navigation.navigate('List')
```

Comment: Calling .pop() before navigating to the next screen worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset

Based on the answers above, with little improvements this is what worked for me:

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const SplashScreen = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) {
      navigation.dispatch(state => {
        const routes = state.routes.filter(item => item.name !== 'SplashScreen');

        return CommonActions.reset({ ...state, routes, index: routes.length - 1 });
      });
    }
  }, [isFocused, navigation]);

  ...

  return ...
}
```